# Converting a BigInteger into a Key

Tags: java, encryption, aes

how do i cast a Big Integer into a Key for java cryptography library?
I am trying to use a shared diffie hellman key that i generated myself for the key value for AES encryption.

Below is the code that i used

> ```
> BigInteger bi; long value = 1000000000;
> ```
>
> bi = BigInteger.valueOf(value); 
>   Key key = new Key (bi);

however it did not work.
May i know how do i convert a BigInteger value into a Key value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Key` is an interface, you cannot instantiate it

Answer (score 2):

First, you cannot cast it.  There is no relationship between the `BigInteger` class and the `Key` interface.

Second, `Key` is an interface not a class, so you can't create instances of it.  What you need to create is an instance of some class that implements `Key`.  And it most likely needs to be a specific implementation class, not (say) an anonymous class.

The final thing is that the Java crypto APIs are designed to hide the representation of the key.  To create a key from bytes, you need to create a `KeySpec` object; e.g. [`SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html)) and then use a `KeyFactory` to "generate" a key from it.  Typical `KeySpec` constructors take a `byte[]` as a parameter, so you first need to get the byte array from your `BigInteger` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your `BigInteger` to a byte array of a specific size, then use the first (leftmost) bytes to create a key. For this you need to know the size of the prime p used in DH, as the value needs to be left-padded to represent a key. I would suggest to use standardized DH parameters (or at least make sure that the size of the prime is dividable by 8).

Note that there may be a zero valued byte in front of the byte array retrieved using [`BigInteger.toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29) because the value returned is *encoded* as a *signed* (two-complement) big-endian byte array. You need to remove this byte if the result is bigger than the prime (in bytes) because of it.

```
public static byte[] encodeSharedSecret(final BigInteger sharedSecret, final int primeSizeBits) {

    // TODO assignment add additional tests on input

    final int sharedSecretSize = (primeSizeBits + Byte.SIZE - 1) / Byte.SIZE;

    final byte[] signedSharedSecretEncoding = sharedSecret.toByteArray();
    final int signedSharedSecretEncodingLength = signedSharedSecretEncoding.length;

    if (signedSharedSecretEncodingLength == sharedSecretSize) {
        return signedSharedSecretEncoding;
    }

    if (signedSharedSecretEncodingLength == sharedSecretSize + 1) {
        final byte[] sharedSecretEncoding = new byte[sharedSecretSize];
        System.arraycopy(signedSharedSecretEncoding, 1, sharedSecretEncoding, 0, sharedSecretSize);
        return sharedSecretEncoding;
    }

    if (signedSharedSecretEncodingLength < sharedSecretSize) {
        final byte[] sharedSecretEncoding = new byte[sharedSecretSize];
        System.arraycopy(signedSharedSecretEncoding, 0,
                sharedSecretEncoding, sharedSecretSize - signedSharedSecretEncodingLength, signedSharedSecretEncodingLength);
        return sharedSecretEncoding;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Shared secret is too big");
}
```

After that you need to derive the key bytes using some kind of key derivation scheme. The one you should use depends on the standard you are implementing:

As stated in [RFC 2631](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2631.txt)

> X9.42 provides an algorithm for generating an essentially arbitrary
>   amount of keying material from ZZ. Our algorithm is derived from that 
>   algorithm by mandating some optional fields and omitting others.
>
> ```
>  KM = H ( ZZ || OtherInfo)
> ```
>
> H is the message digest function SHA-1 [FIPS-180] ZZ is the shared 
>   secret value computed in Section 2.1.1. Leading zeros MUST be
>   preserved, so that ZZ occupies as many octets as p.

Note that I have discovered a bug in the Bouncy Castle libraries up to 1.49 (that's the *current* version at this date) in the DH implementation regarding the secret extraction - it does strip the spurious leading 00h valued bytes, but it forgets to left-pad the result up to the prime size p. This will lead to an incorrect derived key once in 192 times (!)